# Group owner on SharePoint

Tags: permissions, groups

When creating groups on SharePoint, how important is it who the owner of the group is? I tried setting the owner to an AD group but it said that was not possible. Can we set one custom group's owner to another SharePoint group that contains the administrators of the site collection? It doesn't make sense to set the group owner to an individual who might leave the organization.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the owner is important because other than site collection admins, they are the only ones that can manage that group. Yes, you can have another sharepoint group be a group owner.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. Your help is appreciated :) I'm still trying to wrap my brain around the groups concept.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with:

1. Create a SharePoint group with no permissions to the site.
2. Add AD group to this SharePoint group
3. Assign this SharePoint group as an Owner of the other SharePoint group